# Checking function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on some CS homework and this is my first experience with Haskell, so I have a question.

I've declared a data type

```
data Date = Date Int Int Int deriving (Show)
```

and I have this function testdate:

```
testdate :: Date -> Maybe Date
testdate (Date m d y) = if 1 <= m && m <= 12 && 1 <= d && d <= 31 && y >= 0
    then
        True
    else
        False
```

I want to make a new function that checks to see if testdate is true or false, then returns to you the date.
something like:

```
betterdate :: Date -> Maybe Date
betterdate (Date m d y) if (testdate = True) //I know this part doesn't work
     then Just (Date m d y) 
     else Nothing
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You don't need the `if ... then True else False` in the definition of `testdate`.  The `1 <= m && ... && y >= 0` expression evaluates to `True` or `False` on its own, so your function can just be that.

Comment: Also, when you are comparing two things, you use the equality operator which is `==` not `=`. You are also comparing a function to a Bool, which doesn't make sense (as in, it doesn't type check). You probably meant to do this `testdate (Date m d y) == True`.

Comment: The function `testDate` has the wrong type: it claims to return `Maybe Date`, but actually returns `Bool`. You'll need to give it the correct type (or omit the type entirely to let haskell infer it for you) in order to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to pass your date to the `testdate` function. This should work:

```
betterdate d = if testdate d
    then Just d
    else Nothing
```

If you really want to unpack the `Date` in the parameter list then you can do this to avoid duplicating `(Date m d y)` everwhere:

```
betterdate date@(Date m d y) = if testdate date
    then Just date
    else Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realize it would be so simple. Appreciate the help

Comment: Higher-level version: `betterdate = mfilter testdate . Just`. (`mfilter` is in `Control.Monad`.)